# Tridion 2013 Experience Manager fails to update the preview because of internal server error

Tags: content-delivery, experience-manager

I have installed and configured Tridion 2013. It is working like a charm now. Then I've installed and configured the Experience Manager without any visible problems. But when I tried to test it on a HelloWorld page, it failed to update the preview with an `{"error":"Internal Server error"}` message.

I recorded a short video showing what the problem is and how it happens - http://screencast.com/t/yPKhLLrh.

This error also appears sometimes when I try to just open my HelloWorld page in the browser. It seems that it happens randomly.

I've installed the Experience Manager Web Service following the video provided by the live SDL Tridion 2013 documentation. Yesterday I had no such a problem and I haven't changed anything...

Have anyone of you ever experienced the same problem or at least similar?

Do you have any suggestions/advice?

Thank you in advance and looking forward to your replies.

Comment: +1 for the screencast, nice! I'll have to start asking others to literally *show me* their problem. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that you have an "Internal Server Error" the logical place to start is on the server logs.

You need to understand the flow of actions that happen when you click "Update Preview" (I described them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10802033/866454)) and pretty much follow the trail to find out which of the elements involved is throwing the error. That will allow you to determine which log file(s) to look at.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply, Nuno. I was looking at the log files and also looking what exactly is happening using web developer in Firefox. So it was like working fine, with OK responses, and then I clicked on update view and 500 Internal server error showed. Here is a screenshot of it http://screencast.com/t/l3lU5jHeuK There is some kind of an error there, I don't know anything about it.

Comment: Issue resolved! Thanks, Nuno. Your answer actually helped me because I went deep into my config files and found a wrong spelled server name in the cd_storage_config file.